# WebAssembly speed in different languages

Tags: webassembly

Does execution speed change in different languages for WASM? I saw that there is huge difference of wasm file size in different languages, but I cannot find good articles about the speed.
Can I expect the almost the same execution speed in different languages for wasm? Or the original speed of each language may influence the wasm in a way?

Comment: Languages don’t have speeds, so they don’t have original speed either. It’s all up to the compiler, code you write, all kinds of things. So it’s impossible to say, but no, you shouldn’t expect any non-trivial piece of code to have the same “speed” in Python, C, Java etc when compiled to WASM since they’re run in very different ways.

Answer (score 0):

As @sami-kuhmonen put it, languages don't have speed. However, in practice, it's useful to benchmark implementations and how the usual implementation of an algorithm runs.

There are articles about WASM language speeds, [this](https://sami-kuhmonen) being one that I know of. Rust beats AssemblyScript beats Go (TinyGo) on the Chrome WASM engine (which technically you can also use with Node).

There is also [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J5Rs9oG3FdI&t=2139s) presentation from ag_dubs, where you can find some qualitative (as opposed to quantitative) slides describing code size, as well as speed iirc, at roughly that timestamp.

As with any other speed question, you can start programming, thinking "I'll use Rust, because it's faster", but you will have to benchmark your actual code to see that. It's easy in any language to make it unnecessarily slow.